# Animation frames shifted a few pixels away from last frames location

Tags: animation, libgdx

In Libgdx I've been using textureAtlas and for loops to get animation which nearly works, for whatever reason the animation shifts as if the numbers in the for loop aren't correct or the frames each have padding and I can't figure out why. I use https://code.google.com/archive/p/libgdx-texturepacker-gui/downloads and these are the settings I use: https://i.stack.imgur.com/iJc3e.jpg and here's a video of what it looks like: https://imgur.com/a/bo0denv.

I've tried many combinations of settings when making the texture atlas and it does result in various combinations, I even got it to work once but I had to add a new sprite to the texture atlas and couldn't replicate it successfully. All images are exactly the same size and the pigeon is in the same spot in all of them. The sprites placement (attached to box2body that doesn't move on x axis) and size are never changed

Here's the code for the for loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    frames.add(new TextureRegion(getTexture(), 4395 + (i * 74), 42, 74, 74));
}
healedPigeonFlying = new Animation<>(0.15f, frames);
frames.clear();
```

I expect the pigeons body to stay in the same place yet it shifts around as if numbers are wrong or padding is between each frame.

Comment: You'll save yourself a lot of headache by using TexturePacker.

Answer (score 0):

After switching to TexturePacker I was given a warning that solved my problem; apparently using images OVER 4096x4096 will cause issues (like in this post) on almost all modern phones, and images OVER 2048x2048 will cause issues on slightly older phones. My image was 8192x8192. I promptly switched back to my old program and managed to squeeze all my sprites into two different 2048x2018 texture atlas's and it works like a charm.